# Update table based on row number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an integer field that is used to control the custom display order a record.

Example:

```
SET @rownumber = 0;

SELECT 
@rownumber:=@rownumber+1 AS rownumber, 
slides.displayorder 
WHERE 
active = 1 
ORDER BY displayorder ASC
```

This query gives me a result a bit like this:

```
 rownumber | displayorder
-----------+-------------
     1           2
     2           7 
     3           15
     4           50 
     5           80
```

This works OK until a record gets deleted / unapproved (hence the gaps in display order).

What I would like to do is run an update query that sets the `displayorder` column to the value of the rownumber variable after a record is removed.

Giving a result like this:

```
 rownumber | displayorder
-----------+-------------
     1           1
     2           2 
     3           3
     4           4 
     5           5
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why do the gaps matter? The order is preserved on delete. Surely you only need to do something 'clever' on insert / update.

Comment: Are you familiar with using triggers?  An update that is triggered by a delete would do what you're looking for.  That said, I'm curious about your strategy for reordering entries.  Can the user specify that row #5 is now to be displayed between #2 and #3?

Comment: Does this trick (SELECT @var := @var+1..) work in MySql?!?

Comment: Yes, so row 5 would be set to 3 and everything > 3 (not including the record being moved would) be increased by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to do the job.

```
SET @rownumber = 0;
INSERT INTO slides (id, displayorder) 
SELECT a.id, a.rownumber 
FROM (SELECT id, (@rownumber:=@rownumber+1) AS rownumber FROM slides WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY displayorder ASC) AS a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE displayorder = a.rownumber
```